# How to return a single element from a Vec from a function?

Tags: vector, rust, reference, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm new to Rust, and I'm trying to make an interface where the user can choose a file by typing the filename from a list of available files.

This function is supposed to return the `DirEntry` corresponding to the chosen file:

```
fn ask_user_to_pick_file(available_files: Vec<DirEntry>) -> DirEntry {
  println!("Which month would you like to sum?");
  print_file_names(&available_files);
  let input = read_line_from_stdin();

  let chosen = available_files.iter()
      .find(|dir_entry| dir_entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap() == input )
      .expect("didnt match any files");

  return chosen
}
```

However, it appears `chosen` is somehow borrowed here? I get the following error:

```
35 |     return chosen
   |            ^^^^^^ expected struct `DirEntry`, found `&DirEntry`
```

Is there a way I can "unborrow" it? Or do I have to implement the `Copy` trait for `DirEntry`?

If it matters I don't care about the`Vec` after this method, so if "unborrowing" `chosen` destroys the `Vec`, thats okay by me (as long as the compiler agrees).

Comment: `std::fs::DirEntry` does not implement `Copy` or `Clone`, so borrowing is all you can do. Perhaps you could store something else in the vec, like a `Path`, which can be cloned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` so you get owned values instead of references out of the iterator. After that change the code will compile and work as expected:

```rust
fn ask_user_to_pick_file(available_files: Vec<DirEntry>) -> DirEntry {
    println!("Which month would you like to sum?");
    print_file_names(&available_files);
    let input = read_line_from_stdin();

    let chosen = available_files
        .into_iter() // changed from iter() to into_iter() here
        .find(|dir_entry| dir_entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap() == input)
        .expect("didnt match any files");

    chosen
}
```